# How to blur an image halfway/not fully in keynote?

Tags: keynote, text, animation

I'm making a keynote presentation (animation, really) where there's an image on the slide. Next, after a few seconds, some text moves in on top of the image, and what I want is for that image to simultaneously blur (albeit not fully - maybe 50% blur, kinda like they do in movies when focusing on one person and not the other, if you know what I mean). I know there's a blur animation, but when I tried it, it fully blurred out the image. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the following under macOS BigSur 11.4 and Keynote version 11.1, yet I remember this functionality has been there a **very** long time.

1. Select the image you want to blur.
2. Select "animate" in the top right corner: 
   [image]
3. Right below select "action" 
   [image]
4. Click on "add action" and select "opacity"
5. You will now have a slider for both duration and opacity [image]